# Python 2.7 line replace overwrites beginning of line only in linux server

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, replace, overwrite

I have a code that parses strings from a file and replaces them with values using a dictionary. When I run the code on my local machine (windows 10 64bit) it works but when I upload it to an amazon linux server the error occures.
Code example:

```
for line2 in before_makeover:
    to_be_replaced = []
    no_letters = ""
    flag = re.findall(".*[_!@#$%^&*]+.*", line2)
    if len(flag) == 0:
        n_log.write(line2)
        print line2
        continue
    for letter in line2:
        if letter in string.letters + "\n" + " " + string.digits:
            if len(no_letters) > 0:
                if no_letters in rules.keys():
                    to_be_replaced.append(no_letters)
                    no_letters = ''
                    continue
                else:
                    no_letters = ''
            else:
                continue
        else:
            no_letters += letter
            continue
    self.logging("to be replaced %s\n" % to_be_replaced)
    self.logging("Line %s" % line2)
    for to_be in to_be_replaced:
        line2 = string.replace(line2, to_be, rules[to_be], 1)
        self.logging("after replace %s" % line2)
    n_log.writelines(line2)
    print line2
```

`self.logging` is a method for my own logging and is not relevant for the question.

Comment: Please also post error message

Comment: It doesn't print an error code what is does is: 
example line = "WR_1" 
it should output "WR 1"
but it outputs "1R"

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: How do I get it>